# How to disable saved/modified markers in Visual Studio?

Tags: settings, visual-studio-2022

VS2022 displays for example green vertical lines (next to line numbers) as indicators of saved changes. How to disable/hide those markers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Tools → Options → Text Editor → General and uncheck "Track Changes":

[image]

This should disable the green lines (saved changes) and yellow lines (unsaved changes) you get near the line numbers, as well as in the scroll bar.

Comment: How can I disable change marks near line numbers only? It is annoying as everytime I click there to select lines it opens some popup I am not interested in. At the moment I have disabled them all. The VS is getting more and more complicated and not handy as it was before.

Comment: @ADM-IT I am actually using the preview version of Visual Studio 2022, and *I believe* (but I am not certain) that the thing that controls what you are talking about is the new line staging support feature that is in the Preview Features options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/99kj9.png.  I actually asked/answered my own question about this in regards to the color changes to these indicators that this feature does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72142182/how-to-change-the-colors-of-the-modified-lines-indicator-in-version-17-2

Comment: Thanks mate. That is what I was looking for. For git changes preview and blame I use GitExtensions.