# How to remove git difference indicators in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I opened Visual Studio 2022 today and got these symbols on my left sidebar.

[image]

I didn't enable those, they just appeared. If i click on them, they show this:

[image]

They are really annoying, especially since the red arrows appear on the right sidebars in nearly the same color as error indicators.

[image]

I couldn't find an option to turn these off, or find a solution online. Does anyone know how to get rid of them?

Comment: They're there to show you what you've changed in the code since last commit. They'll "go away" as soon as you commit your changes. If you really want to turn it off - even when there are changes in your worktree - you have to turn to "hacks" (i.e. non-supported operations) https://gist.github.com/hmemcpy/5bc6b5cc11050b502ca3

Comment: The real question is why in the world they decided to use the same color as errors, given that there are 16M+ colors...

Comment: @Sasino Exactly what I thought the first time I saw it..

Answer (score 16):

As of Version 17.6.2 this is no longer a preview feature. This is now fully implemented and turned on, again, by default. To disable go to:

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `General`

From there you want to uncheck "Track Changes".

Comment: The problem is that this also removes the non-Git margin colors for saved/unsaved file changes. I can't find a way to have those but not the Git ones.

Comment: I agree that these should be two different features that can be enabled separately (track changes being based on local file status, and git indicators being based on git check-in status). Also, in my view, the new shapes / colors look indeed much more obtrusive / distracting.

Comment: Thank you!  This has been a pain for some time now.

Comment: This is now possible currently in the preview version of Visual Studio as I [described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74181964/6530134) Expect it to be in the stable version at some point.

Answer (score 11):

**Updated Answer (February 16<sup>th</sup>, 2024):**

For a time, Visual Studio forced this option upon you with no way to disable it after making this feature no longer a preview one.  However, Visual Studio 2022 17.9.0 added the ability to toggle between the modes now after a recent [feedback item](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Interactive-line-staging-overrides-Track/10366114).

Go to Tools → Options → Text Editor → General and change the "Tracking Mode" dropdown to either be Git Changes or File Changes:

[image: tracking mode option in settings]

---

**Original Answer:**

You will want to turn off Git Line Staging support.

Go to Tools → Options → Environment → Preview Features and uncheck the "Git line-staging support" option and restart the IDE.

[image]

Visual Studio Version 17.3 turned [this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-line-staging?view=vs-2022) on by default.  By turning it off, Visual Studio will revert back to having the "green and yellow" change indicator bars instead of these Git ones. It will also remove those red arrows you speak of.

Comment: Do you know if something has changed since your last comment or there is a feature vote somewhere to make this thing optional again?

Comment: @yasirkula https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Interactive-line-staging-overrides-Track/10366114?q=line+staging this looks promising - fix might be in the works for a future (and soon?) update.

Comment: @yasirkula if you are still looking for a fix, the latest Preview release of Visual Studio contains one (see updated answer).  Expect it to go to the stable version in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a specific setting for only switch off the line staging eighter. But there is a toggle-button ***Show staging controls*** on the **top right corner** of the Text-Editor to switch it off.

[image: see here]

Comment: I don't think this button does anything in regards to the question being asked.

Comment: You are right. I was too focused on the first answer how to turn off the Git Line Staging support.

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't like how Microsoft moves every option with every single minor update. I HATE the Line Staging button, it's the most annoying feature (and completely unwanted feature) I've ever dealt with. You're the only person who has actually told us how to turn it off in new versions of VS, so thank you. It may not answer this OPs question, but it answered the question I've been specifically looking for for 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to "disable" this (kinda):
So far, Microsoft still hasn't provided a way to disable this, but I found how to change a color of line-staging indicator to gray, so that it's no longer visible near line numbers or in the scrollbar:

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors.

Select **Track deletions in documents under source control** and change to color matching your theme.
[image]

I have VS in dark mode so I set it to gray. If you're using light mode, probably set it to white and it won't bother you anymore.

If you want them to add a way to disable line-staging fully, you can share your feedback here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/line-staging-interactive-staging/
I hope they'll pay attention if many people complain.