# Hide diff markers in left margin

Tags: visual-studio-2022

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to hide these. It doesn't appear to be a margin that can be turned off, and I also disabled "Track changes". Any ideas?

This is in 17.6.3, I don't know if they appeared in earlier versions of VS 2022, as I only recently started migrating to it.

Comment: That's it, I missed it in my search - dup question, thanks.

Comment: I think whenever the upcoming 17.7 release is released, the option in the duplicate will be removed (as [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74164582/how-to-remove-git-difference-indicators-in-visual-studio-2022#comment134867371_74181964) on the answer mentions).  I am currently running the 17.7 Preview 1 release and the option is gone, and I can't find a way to disable these indicators anymore.

Comment: @TimothyG. That would be in keeping with Microsoft's increasing "you will do things our way" attitude.