# Disable git modified lines and red triangle indicator in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In a recent update Microsoft (without asking or telling us how to disable it or making it easy to disable) switched on what seems like Git changes in in the left gutter (screen shot attached), with red triangle for 'Deleted' and blue lines as 'Modified'

I've spent hours looking for a way to disable this, all I found is a SO question about changing the colours (which I don't want to do) with an answer about how to turn it off, but that no longer exists (it was a preview feature and I searched for the text and it isn't in options at all now:
[How to change the colors of the modified lines indicator in version 17.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72142182/how-to-change-the-colors-of-the-modified-lines-indicator-in-version-17-2)

How can I turn this off?

Thanks