# Is there a way to turn off Gits delete line marker in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

These are from the Git integration telling me that I have removed a line (different from the previous commit) in a file in Visual Studio.

Its just annoying when you're refactoring a large file and there's a million red markers down the right hand site of the class stopping you from distinguishing it from the actual error red markers. Obviously this is not a massive problem but what would be nice is if it was not on by default or maybe even just a different colour.

Anyone know how to turn this off at least?

Also, if this also annoys you please help the cause:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Remove-Red-Arrow-Indicating-Delete-Git/10150017?port=1025&fsid=4e7cff19-011d-4fa4-88b8-2de47a5df715&entry=problem

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using? For me, in 2022, the git block markers are applied on the left hand side of the scroll bar and the error markers are on the right of the scrollbar. The delete arrow is shown in the left hand margin rather than on the right. E.g. all of the markers are placed in distinct locations, I'm not sure how you'd confuse them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you disable Gutter Indicators in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969277/how-can-you-disable-gutter-indicators-in-vs-code)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever noone said confused, just annoying

Comment: You said it was "stopping you from distinguishing it from the actual error red markers" - I asked how this was happening since they're shown in different places? One of us must be confused about something.

Comment: this is terrible!! Any solution? also, seriously, who is this Damien guy. Like people don't have different preferences and visual habits. Wait let me answer it like @Damien_The_Unbeliever will understand:

"Ah yes, like other humans are not accustomed to processing different visual input in different ways..."

Answer (score 0):

Hey fellow person who gets annoyed by this: Turn them off with this answer. (I personally would rather have no markers, than these annoying red ones everywhere)

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General:

`[ ] Track Changes (uncheck)`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72128054/2213321